# canvas drag and drop with multiple items

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am creating a multiple item drag and drop for a project and have a reached a wall.

At present I have 5 square items I have added to the canvas and also stored there x, y, width,  height, bgcolour into an array called items. I have detected when the mouse selects one of these squares and can drag an item around. However my issue is that the item I am dragging around is always the same item, the first one added to the canvas. If anybody could help me work out how to detect which item specifically I have selected that would be great.

There is a'lot of code so I will try and post only the required bits.

```
//Items are added to canvas and values added to items[];
//a click event runs when the canvas is clicked, the following code is then run
var mouseCheck = function(e) {
            var length = items.length;

            var pos = $('#scalesPlatform').offset(),
                top = pos.top,
                left = pos.left,
                mx = e.pageX - left,
                my = e.pageY - top;

                var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(mx, my, 1, 1);

                if (imagedata.data[3] > 0) {
                    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        var hit = items[i];
                        offsetX = mx - items[i].x;
                        offsetY = my - items[i].y;
                        hit.x = mx - offsetX;
                        hit.y = my - offsetY;


                        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {

                            move(hit, drag, items, event);
                        });
                        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
                            drag = false;
                            move(hit, drag, event);
                        });
                    }
                }

        }
```

The issue is I need the variable hit to equal the item I have selected.
Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: `event.target` is the object under target when you drag any element. Maybe you can fetch the id or name of the object and pass its correspondent from the items array in your move function will do

Answer (score 0):

**Here’s how to drag/drop with multiple items**

You have your squares defined in objects:

```
var items=[]
items.push({x:0,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"red",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:70,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"green",isDragging:false});
items.push({x:140,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"blue",isDragging:false});
```

So you can hit test like this to detect which item(s) will be dragged:

```
function setDragging(x,y){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        var item=items[i];

        // if x/y hit this item, set it’s isDragging flag
        if(x>=item.x && x<=item.x+item.width && y>=item.y && y<=item.y+item.height){
            item.isDragging=true;
        }

    }
}
```

Your mousemove handler calculates the distance of the drag.

```
      dragX=mouseX-startX;
      dragY=mouseY-startY;
```

Then in your draw() function you can handle both dragging and non-dragging items.

Items being dragged will be drawn at their original position plus dragX/dragY.

```
if(item.isDragging){
    ctx.rect(item.x+dragX,item.y+dragY,item.width,item.height);
}else{
    ctx.rect(item.x,item.y,item.width,item.height);
}
```

Here is example code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/62L9q/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var isMouseDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;
    var dragX;
    var dragY;

    var items=[]
    items.push({x:0,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"red",isDragging:false});
    items.push({x:70,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"green",isDragging:false});
    items.push({x:140,y:10,width:50,height:50,color:"blue",isDragging:false});

    draw();

    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            var item=items[i];
            if(isMouseDown){

            }
            ctx.beginPath();
            if(item.isDragging){
                ctx.rect(item.x+dragX,item.y+dragY,item.width,item.height);
            }else{
                ctx.rect(item.x,item.y,item.width,item.height);
            }
            ctx.fillStyle=item.color
            ctx.fill();
        }
    }


    function setDragging(x,y){
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            var item=items[i];
            if(x>=item.x && x<=item.x+item.width && y>=item.y && y<=item.y+item.height){
                item.isDragging=true;
            }
        }
    }

    function clearDragging(x,y){
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            var item=items[i];
            if(item.isDragging){
                items[i].isDragging=false;
                item.x+=dragX;
                item.y+=dragY;
            }
        }
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      setDragging(startX,startY);
      isMouseDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
      clearDragging();
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isMouseDown=false;
      clearDragging();
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      if(isMouseDown){
          dragX=mouseX-startX;
          dragY=mouseY-startY;
          draw(mouseX,mouseY);
      }

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```