# Using Drag and Drop multiple icons onto an image that is the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have been struggling for a few days to implement the following functionality in HTML, CSS, JavaScript (prefer not to use jquery or any other external library).

Tool bar on top which shows a list of images (png based).

Load a canvas under this tool bar that has the  image (png based) of an irregular shape (depicting a land area to be developed) and any images that have been previously placed on this.

Allow user to drag and drop an image from the tool bar to the canvas and to reposition it as desired on the canvas.

Allow removal of the image on the canvas, this puts it back in the tool bar.

Save the updated canvas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you like us to write your work for you? Or have you made any attempts so far we can actually help you with?

Comment: I have used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424623/canvas-drag-and-drop-with-multiple-items

Comment: I have resolved the questions of this post by utilizing as the basis for my project the code posted by    https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/html5-drag-and-drop-multiple-objects-on-the-canvas-element/?unapproved=4205&moderation-hash=232334f6bae2032ff677cad17c0f1539#comment-4205